# How to make openshift take the right artifact in maven build

Tags: maven, spring-boot, openshift

I'm trying to build a spring boot application from source in openshift.

```
oc new-app redhat-openjdk18-openshift~<git_repo_URL>
```

It builds and there is no error.

But! The problem I'm facing is that we are using the "exec" classifier in the maven plugin for spring boot. This results in two jar files in the target folder. "app.jar" and "app-exec.jar. Openshift uses the app.jar instead of the app-exec.jar in the build and this results in that the application will not start.

Is there a way to tell openshift which jar to use?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <classifier>exec</classifier>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/index#configuration_environment_variables it looks like specifying the following environment variable should work (with or without the `.jar` extension, I'm not sure)

```
JAVA_APP_JAR=app-exec
```